# Getting an extra row of Nones when trying to flatten a list of lists with map or list comprehensions , why?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

`lol = [[7, 1, 0], [10, 2, 5], [6, 5, 9], [9, 9, 9], [1, 23, 12]]`

when I try to flatten it using maps and  list comprehensions and try to print it out in separate lines I get one extra row at the end containing Nones , why ?

```
Option 1 : >>> list(map(lambda x : print(x),[' '.join(map(str,triples)) for triples in lol]))

Option 2 : >>> list(map(lambda x : print(x) , list(map(lambda x : ' '.join(map(str,x)),lol))))
```

The output I am getting in both cases is :

```
7 1 0

10 2 5

6 5 9

9 9 9

1 23 12

[None, None, None, None, None]
```

why the extra row of 'None's at the end ?

Comment: `print()` returns `None` you care collecting the values returned by `print()` and printing as a side-effect. What is the result you want? If you just want to flatten the nested list, use the search. There are **many** answers already here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not something that you are printing but something that you are storing.

You first print all the elements and then you are storing the output of the print statement which is None

```
for triples in lol: print(' '.join(map(str,triples))) # if you just want to print
lolz = [' '.join(map(str,triples)) for triples in lol] # if you just want to store
print(lolz)
```